# What is this native North American lily with a downward facing speckled orange flower?

Tags: identification, flowers, bulbs, lily

I suspect this is a native North American lily that I grew from seed and the label was lost over the years they take to flower.

It's quite happy in full sun in USDA zone 4 in Ottawa.  It has a nodding flower which hangs downward. For the picture I held the flower up. Any ideas on which species?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think its Lilium superbum - the petals are much more reflexed on that plant, curling back so far as to almost touch the trumpet at the back. Much more likely it's Lilium canadense, or the Canada Lily - can be yellow, orange or red, usually found growing in damper places.